# How to tell if the top-right corner is visible in an editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>` that is set to be content editable and has a fixed height. On overflow the `<div>` shows vertical scrollbar. What I want is to detect absolute coordinates of the top-right (or top-left) point of images in my editable `<div>` especially when the image is partly visible. Is it possible? More important, is there a way to tell whether the top-right point is visible to the user or it is scrolled outside view?

Any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

This should illustrate my idea:

[image: Editable div with some content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the X/Y (top left) coordinates of the element relative to the *document*.  In order to see whether it's outside of the window, compare it to `$(window).offset()`.  The latter gives you the X/Y coordinates of the current window relative to the document, so if the Y coordinate of the window is higher than the element in question, it's top is off screen.

Comment: But we don't want relative to the *document* here, we want relative to the overflow container...

Answer (score 2):

The "is the top visible" problem is trivial: Just check the div's `scrollTop` and see if it is non-zero (or more specifically: less than the `offsetTop` of the element you are looking for).